# Absolute value of Lebesgue integrable function

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that a measurable function $f$ is Lebesgue integrable iff $|f|$ is.
I've proved the first part  but how can I show if $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable then $f$ is ?

Comment: It cannot be. If $A$ is a non measurable set in $[0,1]$, then define $f = -1 +2(1_A)$. Then $|f|=1$ and isintegrable, but $f$ is not.

Comment: Maybe you are looking to add the hypothesis that $f$ is measurable function into the (possibly extended) reals?

Comment: Look at $f^+$ and $f^-$

Comment: @leo's comment hold the key...

Answer (score 8):

Well the both parts are easy.

If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable than $f^+$ and $f^-$ are Lebesgue integrable, so integral of both $f^+$ and $f^-$ is finite. Thus, their sum is also finite, which means, integral of $|f|$ is finite. If $f$ is measurable than $|f|$ is measurable. If you combine last 2 statements, you get that $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Same in the other direction, if $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable, $f^+$ and $f^-$ are also, so integral of $f^+$ and integral of $f^-$ are finite, thus their subtraction is finite, which is integral of $f$.

$f^+ = \max\{0,f\}$

$f^- = \max\{0,-f\}$

$f = f^+ - f^-$

$|f|= f^+ + f^-$

Answer (score 6):

This is not true.  Let $M$ be a non-measurable "monster" set contained in $[0,1]$
Define $f(x) = 1$ if $x\in M$ and $-1$ otherwise.  We see that $|f| = 1$ on $[0,1]$ so $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable.  Since $M$ is not measurable, $f$ is not.

Comment: I'm considering measurable functions.